# invalid redirect uri while using facebook javascript sdk

Tags: facebook

my channel url is set as

```
channelUrl : '//www.example.com/xyx/channel.html'
```

content of channel.html is

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

and my site url is set as follows

```
http://www.example.com/xyz/
```

and i have stored the following code in **common.js** and add this javascript file to 
immediate next to opening body tag.

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'XXXXXXX', // App ID
         channelUrl : '//www.example.com/xyz/channel.html', // Channel File    
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
       }(document));
```

after doing all this when i open www.example.com/xyz and click on facebook login button 
i am getting following error in a popup window , does any one has a solution to it ?

i have searched many thread but no luck

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check this [link](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=82131), you would find the same error as yours. All fix suggest that you have misconfigured your application from the Facebook App page.

Comment: Bingo !! i solved it by setting site domain to www.example.com, thanks

Comment: @John So you just downvote because of a "can" after 4 years?

Comment: No, I downvoted because the link is dead. Links going dead is the reason why link-only answers are discouraged, although I understand that it's better than nothing as long as the link's alive. Also, I removed the comment you thought I was referring to as I don't think the comment was actually correct.

Comment: @John The link was just a reference to a similar issue, the actual answer was "a misconfiguration from the app page".

Comment: Ok, I'll undo the downvote when the timer allows me.

Comment: SO says my vote is locked unless the answer is edited, sorry.

Comment: @John next time please comment before you downvote not after if you have some doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Internet Explorer using the JavaScript SDK.  I had a setting array defined like this:

```
    var _facebookSettings = {
        appId: '@Model.Facebook.AppId', // App ID
        channelUrl:'//@Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]/js/channel', // Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
        oauth: true,
        scope: '@Model.Facebook.Scope'
    };
```

I then modified my channelUrl definition to look like this:

channelUrl: document.location.protocol + '//@Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]/js/channel'

Notice the addition of "document.location.protocol" before the channel URL definition.  This fix solved my issue and I no longer get that error.